# Ant: Telnet is not working

Tags: ant, telnet

I am trying the below Ant telnet task:

```
 <telnet userid="uid" password="pass" server="${BT_Server}">
    <read>/u01/appldev/devappl/po/11.5.0/reports</read>
    <write>ls</write>
    <read string="/u01/appldev/devappl/po/11.5.0/reports"/>
 </telnet>
```

It will execute for infinite time after login to the remote server. Getting below message:

Buildfile: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1\build.xml

```
sql_compile:
   [telnet] Unauthorised Access is Illegal
   [telnet] login:
   [telnet] uid
   [telnet]  Password:
```

I need to forcefully terminate the job by pressing ctrl+c. It is giving a message- "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?"

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem. Read actually wait for the text which is appearing at the UNIX prompt.

```
<telnet userid="uid" password="pass" server="${Server}">
    <read>authorisation (Y/N)? :</read>
    <write>y</write>
    <read>to continue</read>
    <write>\n</write>
    <read>/export/home/appldev></read4>
    <write>sh test_sql.sh "{$Release_Name}"</write>
    <read string="DEV - uid@host:/export/home/appldev>"/>
</telnet>
```

Comment: I am also using the same, i am executing an bat file on remote machine which starts a port, but when ant completes its task it closes the port i want to use this port to run my app on the remote, it should be closed only when i want to close. so can you please help me with your experince. Thanks